# Designing a Resourceful app

Tags: php, web-services, laravel, laravel-4

I'm designing my first Resourceful app and building with Laravel 4, which I'm new to as well.

I want to make a booking system, so I treat "booking" as a resource.

However, if I want to query all the bookings of one day, which action should I use? And how should I structure it?

One way I can think about is to put it under index action,
so you query it using the url "/booking?day=2013-08-12", it would be processed like this:

```
public function index(){
  $day=Request::get('day');
  $bookings=Booking::where('day','=',$day)->get();  //something like this
  ...
}
```

Another is using a different controller method:
so the url "/booking/getByDay/2013-08-12" would be like this:

```
public function getByDay($day){
  ...
}
```

Am I thinking in the right way? What's the right way of structuring it?

Comment: The route `/booking/2013-08-12` is shortest & prettiest. Also it is understood that you are querying by *date* so you don't need to add the 'getByDay' part (that is more dev-friendly than user-friendly). I would prefer to use this instead of a query string. For the sake of sexyness.

Comment: Hi Rubens! I may still need to query bookings by id(or other identifiers), so "/booking/201308121234" should lead to a different controller in this case. That's my concern about using query string. Also, should I related all the queries to a default "action" in terms of resourceful, or I can create something new?

Comment: Personally, I would handle this case with different routes with constrains. That way I could handle both `/booking/2013-08-12` and `/booking/201308121234` and direct each to a specific controller/action.